# Objective-C - Iterating two elements deep at once

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, iteration

I was hoping that there is a slick trick out there for iterating over a list in Objective-C, two elements deep.

```
for (Point *startPoint, endPoint in points) {
    drawLine(startPoint,endPoint);
}
```

Basically this should draw a connected line as such:

points[0] -- points[1]

points[1] -- points[2]

points[2] -- points[3]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < points.count -1; i++)
{
    drawLine(points[i], points[i+1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a for loop with a counter variable

```
for(int t=0; t < points.count - 1; t++)
{
    drawline([points objectAtIndex:t], [points objectAtIndex:t + 1]);
}
```

As with all situations where you're iterating, make sure you don't go out of bounds.

Comment: FYI, Xcode 4.4 and newer supports collection subscripting, so syntax `array[index]` is valid.

Comment: Why t for an iterator?

Comment: @Kreiri Good, wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @Justin Because t was the first letter that came to mind, I also thought it felt wrong, but when I consulted with my brain a second time it insisted that I use t. Sorry, must be the heat

Comment: @PaulG haha do what you want I have just never seen it before, usually it goes i, j, k, l etc